# Extracing specific tags from arbitrary plain text

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, antlr4, text-parsing

I want to parse plain text comments and look for certain tags within them. The types of tags I'm looking for look like:

```
<name#1234>
```

Where "name" is a [a-z] string (from a fixed list) and "1234" represents a [0-9]+ number. These tags can occur within a string zero or more times and be surrounded by arbitrary other text. For example, the following strings are all valid:

```
"Hello <foo#56> world!"
"<bar#1>!"
"1 &lt; 2"
"+<baz#99>+<squid#0> and also<baz#99>.\n\nBy the way, maybe <foo#9876>"
```

The following strings are all NOT valid:

```
"1 < 2"
"<foo>"
"<bar#>"
"Hello <notinfixedlist#1234>"
```

The last one isn't valid because "notinfixedlist" isn't a supported named identifier.

I can easily parse this using simple regex, for example (I'm omitting named groups for simplicity sake):

```
<[a-z]+#\d+>
```

or specifying a fixed list directly:

```
<(foo|bar|baz|squid)#\d+>
```

but I'd like to use antlr for a few reasons:

- I want anything that doesn't match that format to result in a parse error, so if the text contains "<" or ">" but doesn't match the pattern, it fails. Those characters must be escaped as "&lt;" and "&gt;" respectively if it's not a tag.
- I may extend this in the future to support other kinds of patterns (eg: "{foo+666}" or "[[@1234]]" and would like to avoid an explosion of regex statements. Having a single grammar file I can extend would be great.
- I like the fact that antlr4 implements the visitor pattern and my code gets called when a tag of a specific type is encountered instead of having to hack together varying regex.

How do I implement such a grammar using antlr4? Most of the examples I've seen are for languages which follow exact rules for the entire text, whereas I only want the grammar to apply to matching patterns within arbitrary text.

I've come up with this, which I believe is correct:

```
grammar Tags;

parse 
    : ( tag | text )*
    ;

tag 
    : '<' fixedlist '#' ID '>'
    ;

fixedlist 
    : 'foo' 
    | 'bar' 
    | 'baz' 
    | 'squid';

text 
    : ~('<' | '>')+
    ;

ID
    : [0-9]+
    ;
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Nicely stated question, but not a good fit for SO as it's primarily opinion based.

Comment: Good point. I'll modify the question to ask specifically how to implement in antlr.

Comment: You can probably have your lexer with just two rules: a TAG and a CHAR, then the grammar is just a `(TAG | CHAR) *`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general terms, the problem identified is typically described an island grammar problem - where sections of an otherwise singular document are described by two or more different, often mutually ambiguous, specifications.

ANTLR 4 directly supports island grammars through use of `mode`s. Note, modes are only available in split lexer/parser grammars.

The parser

```
parser grammar TagsParser ;

options {
    tokenVocab = TagsLexer ;
}

parse   : ( tag | text )* EOF ;
tag     : LANGLE fixedlist GRIDLET ID RANGLE ;
text    : . ;
fixedlist
    : FOO
    | BAR
    | BAZ
    | SQUID
    ;
```

The lexer

```
lexer grammar TagsLexer ;

LANGLE  : '<' -> pushMode(tag) ;
TEXT    : . ;

mode tag ;
    RANGLE  : '>' -> popMode ;

    FOO     : 'foo' ;
    BAR     : 'bar' ;
    BAZ     : 'baz' ;
    SQUID   : 'squid' ;
    GRIDLET : '#' ;
    ID      : [0-9]+ ;

    NONTAG  : . -> popMode ;
```

The `text` rule in the parser will match all tokens not previously consumed by the parser rules above it. This will include all `TEXT` tokens as well as any text that happens to be matched by a tag mode rule but is not validly part of a tag.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `TEXT` definition? It doesn't appear to be used within the lexer grammar, or is there an implied relationship between `text` and `TEXT` I'm missing?

Comment: Anything after the beginning of the document, or a `NONTAG`, and before a `LANGLE` is `TEXT`.

Comment: Yes, I understand that from the parser's `( tag | text )*` line, and `text` matches any character that isn't a tag. I just don't understand the `TEXT` line in the lexer. Put another way, what's the difference between the parser `text : . ;` and the lexer `TEXT : . ;` lines, and when is `TEXT` actually used (it's defined, but appears unused to me)?

Comment: The lexer runs to completion, consuming characters and emitting tokens, before the parser starts. The parser consumes tokens in the process of matching rules. So, `TEXT : . ;` produces a token for each matched character and `text: . ;` matches the `text` rule for very token not previously consumed.

Comment: I tried implementing this but I'm not sure it's valid. It correctly parses `<foo#123>` but it also parses `<foo#123xyz>` which should be invalid. It appears the `xyz` characters are omitted from the token stream. If I inspect the `CommonTokenStream` class, it shows `'<', 'foo', '#', '123', '>', EOF`. Is there something I need to specify as an option or setting to make this work as expected?

Comment: It looks like setting the error handler to use `BailErrorStrategy` does the trick, otherwise it seems antlr tries to recover with the next token.

Comment: Last question if you don't mind: the grammar you provided works well and, with the `BailErrorStrategy` now fails for tags starting with `<` but not matching the pattern. However, if the text contains one or more `>` characters such as the text `a > b` it's not picked up as a parse error due to the `tag` mode not being entered. How can the grammar be modified to cause an error in that case?

Comment: Why should `a > b` be considered invalid text? Probably best to present in a separate question with a complete explanation of what is considered valid text, sample input, and your grammar attempt to express the validity requirements.

Comment: Thank you. [New question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39278948/antlr-grammar-avoiding-angle-brackets) posted.