# antlr grammar avoiding angle brackets

Tags: c#, antlr, antlr4, antlr4cs

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39238433/extracing-specific-tags-from-arbitrary-plain-text) I asked about extracting tags from arbitrary text. The solution provided worked well, but there's one edge case I'd like to handle. To recap, I'm parsing arbitrary user-entered text and would like to have any occurrence of `<` or `>` to conform to valid tag syntax. Where an angle bracket isn't part of a valid tag, it should be escaped as `&lt;` or `&gt;`. The syntax I'm looking for is `<foo#123>` where `foo` is text from a fixed list of entries and `123` is a number `[0-9]+`. The parser:

```
parser grammar TagsParser;

options {
    tokenVocab = TagsLexer;
}

parse: (tag | text)* EOF;
tag: LANGLE fixedlist GRIDLET ID RANGLE;
text: NOANGLE;
fixedlist: FOO | BAR | BAZ;
```

The lexer:

```
lexer grammar TagsLexer;

LANGLE: '<' -> pushMode(tag);
NOANGLE: ~[<>]+;

mode tag:

RANGLE: '>' -> popMode;
GRIDLET: '#';
FOO: 'foo';
BAR: 'bar';
BAZ: 'baz';
ID: [0-9]+;
OTHERTEXT: . ;
```

This works well and successfully parses text such as:

```
<foo#123>
Hi <bar#987>!
<baz#1><foo#2>anythinghere<baz#3>
if 1 &lt; 2
```

It also successfully fails the following when I use the `BailErrorStrategy`:

```
<foo123>
<bar#a>
<foo#123H>
<unsupported#123>
if 1 < 2
```

The last one successfully fails because `<` enters the `tag` mode and it doesn't match a supported tag format. However, I would also like to avoid instances of `>` in the text as well, so the following should fail as well:

```
if 2 > 1
```

That text should be specified as `if 2 &gt; 1` instead of having the raw angle bracket.

How can I modify the grammar so that occurrences of `>` which aren't part of a valid tag fail to parse?

Comment: As your grammar stands now, `>` outside of a tag will cause token recognition error, since it appears nowhere in the lexer grammar outside of the `tag` mode. Isn't that sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your grammar stands now, it will fail `>` outside of a tag with token recognition error, because `>` doesn't appear in the lexer grammar outside of the `tag` mode. That's a failure all right as it is. But if you insist on failing during *parse*, then just add right angle to the lexer's default mode:

```
lexer grammar TagsLexer;

LANGLE: '<' -> pushMode(tag);
NOANGLE: ~[<>]+;
BADRANGLE: '>';

mode tag;

RANGLE: '>' -> popMode;
...
```

Then `>` outside of a tag will fail during parse.

Comment: Thank you, that was deceptively simple! Looks like my knowledge of this stuff has a ways to go.